# C# String Array to Double

Tags: c#, arrays, string, visual-studio-2013, double

Looking for some assistance. I'm sure its really easy, but I just cannot seem to get my head around it.

First, here's my code so far:

```
        //Prompts user to enter numbers
    Console.Write("Enter a line of comma-seperated temperatures: ");
    string temps = Console.ReadLine();
    //Splits commas, seperating numbers into array
    string[] numsInString = temps.Split(',');
    int temps1 = numsInString.Length;
    int[] temps2 = new int[temps1];
    for (int i = 0; i < numsInString.Length; i++)
    {
        temps2[i] = int.Parse(numsInString[i]);
    }


    Console.WriteLine("Minimum temp: " + temps2.Min());
    Console.WriteLine("Average temp: " + temps2.Average());
```

So, it prompts the user to enter a temperature i.e "5" separated by commas, "5,6,7,8". My trouble is that I cannot have temperatures in the decimal range such as "5.4,5.7,6.3,6.8". I've figured out that I need to convert the string to double, but I'm not entirely sure on how to do that.

Thanks

Comment: Your first thought could be that you might try replacing all occurrences of `int` with `double` so you'd have a `double[]` and call `double.Parse`. And if you did that, it'd probably work.

Comment: @CharlesMager I did try that before, but came with the error "Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)" I guess i might have to remove or rearrange some code as well, not too sure -- and those errors point to everything between the [ ]

Comment: OK. Looking a little closer, you don't want to replace `int temps1` and `int i` as `Length` will still be an `int`. You only want to change the type of the `temps2` array and change `int.Parse` to `double.Parse`.

Comment: @CharlesMager that worked! thanks :) that was really easy haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to change the type of your array to `double[]` and then change your parsing to parse `double` instead of `int`:

```
double[] temps2 = new double[temps1];

for (int i = 0; i < numsInString.Length; i++)
{
    temps2[i] = double.Parse(numsInString[i]);
}
```

As a bit of an aside, you can also use LINQ to express this more declaratively:

```
double[] temps2 = temps.Split(',')
    .Select(double.Parse)
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in other answers and comments you need change `int[]` array to `double[]` array and use `double.Parse` method for parsing strings to double.

But instead of loop or LINQ, I want suggest `Array.ConvertAll` method which will convert array of string to array of doubles.

```
Console.Write("Enter a line of comma-seperated temperatures: ");
var rawData = Console.ReadLine();
var rawTemperatures = rawData.Split(',');  
var temperatures = Array.ConvertAll<string, double>(rawTemperatures, double.Parse);
```

`Array.ConvertAll` method will execute same `for` loop, but will be tiny tiny (in your case) more effective and enough declarative then LINQ approach